# < > changed to &lt; &gt; and find_all("a") is unable to extract links with beautifulsoup in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to use BeautifulSoup to extract some links.

The following is the python code I use.

```
resp = urlopen("http://target-page.com").read().decode("utf-8")
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp, "html.parser")
all_links = soup.find_all("a")
for link in all_links:
    print(link["href"])
```

Below is a sample of HTML code I got by `print("soup")`

```
<a href="http://aaa.com">aaa</a>

<div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="tab_0" class="seq_contents tex2jax_ignore asciimath2jax_ignore" id="seq_contents_0">

&lt;a href="http://bbb.com" target="_blank"&gt;

</div>
```

I can get "http://aaa.com" but not "http://bbb.com".

Why are < > changed to `&lt;` `&gt;` (only in this div)?  How to fix it?

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Hmm interesting problem :-) are you sure the original source is not like that? or maybe there is some major html syntax error between those links?

Comment: I double checked the original html code, which is right :-( I viewed the page and its code in Chrome

Comment: get rid of the decode in the resp. bs4 will do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
all_links2 = soup.find_all("div")
for link in all_links:
    print(link["href"])
**for link in all_links2:
    print(link["href"])**
```

You looked through all --> a tags ( tags that start with  for example )
but pages you're looking for are stored in